# Qml ScrollView in ScrollView

Tags: qt, прокрутка, qml, tableview, scrollview

Пример кода:

```
ScrollView
    {
         TableView
         {

         }
    }
```

Если курсор находится между скроллом и таблицей, то колёсико двигает скролл. Если курсор попадает на таблицу, то скролиться начинает таблица.
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при попадании курсора на таблицу скроллиться продолжал корневой скролл, а не содержимое таблицы.

Перекопал всё, что мог: документацию разных версий Qt, Форумы, наш любимый стек, подсказки QtCreator.
Программирую на Qt/qml 1,5 года. (учитывайте при ответах пожалуйста)

- propagateComposedEvents - не помогло
- event.accepted = false - не помогло
- используется версия QtQuick.Controls 1.4 (На 2.x нет возможности перейти)

TableView основан на ScrollView. Не сложно догадаться, что именно он и крадёт событие мышки.

Прошу помочь КОНСТРУКТИВНЫМИ ответами. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Извините, код негде проверить, но вот так тоже не работает?

```
ScrollView
{
    TableView
    {
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onWheel:
            {
                wheel.accepted = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```